# Moment.js time to format

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have this code :

```
var timeUntilUnlock = moment().to(moment.unix(result[0][0].locked))
```

The output is something like , in a hour, in a minute, in a few seconds. I was wondering if there is a way I can covert the output to display the actual number like. :

```
in 00:00:08
```

instead of saying in a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) to get a [duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/):

```
var a = moment();
var b = moment().add(8, 'seconds');

var duration = moment.duration(a.diff(b));
```

You can use the methods on the duration object to get the values you want to display:

```
duration.hours() + ":" + duration.minutes() + ":" + duration.seconds()
```

If you want padded zeroes you'll have to do it yourself:

```
function pad(n) {
  n = Math.abs(n); // to handle negative durations
  return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n;
}

pad(duration.hours()) + ":" + pad(duration.minutes()) + ":" + pad(duration.seconds())
```